# New users automatically following all users

Tags: python, django

I'm building a fake social network for a project in Django. I've implemented allowing users to 'follow' others if desired (or none at all if they choose). But so far every time I create a user, that user automatically 'follows' all other users in the database. I do not know how to fix this.

Here is the model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('Profile',
                                       related_name="followers_profile",
                                       blank=True, symmetrical=False)
    following = models.ManyToManyField('Profile',
                                       related_name="following_profile",
                                       blank=True, symmetrical=False)
    avatar_thumbnail = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='profile_images',
                                        processors=[ResizeToFill(320, 320)],
                                        format='JPEG',
                                        options={'quality': 40},
                                        blank=True)
    feed_type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
                                    default='Both')

    # @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    # def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    #     if created:
    #         Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    #
    # @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    # def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    #     instance.profile.save()

    def get_number_of_followers(self):
        if self.followers.count():
            return self.followers.count()
        else:
            return 0

    def get_number_of_following(self):
        if self.following.count():
            return self.following.count()
        else:
            return 0

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Here is the View that constructs User and Profiles and the form that processes user creation data:

```
def signup(request):
    form = UserCreateForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
            user_profile = Profile(user=user)
            user_profile.save()

            new_user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],

            password=form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            login(request,new_user)
            return redirect('index')
    return render(request, 'userapp/signup.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Here's the UserCreationForm:

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {"username", "email", "password1","password2"}

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email =self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: How do you know user is following all users?

Comment: Checked it in admin panel